# Chart вывод графика

Tags: php, jquery, диаграммы

```
lineChartData = JSON.parse(data);
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: lineChartData
 });
 var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
 window.myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {responsive: true});
```

почему пишет

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'datasets' on string '[{"labels":["Январь","Февраль"],"datasets":{"label":"Продано","borderColor":"#000","backgroundColor":"transparent","pointBorderColor":"#000","pointBackgroundColor":"#000","pointRadius":"5","pointHoverRadius":"10","data":["7750.00","15345.00"]}}]'
```

данные вывожу из php

```
$arrDatasets = array('label' => "Продано",'borderColor' => "#000", 'backgroundColor' => "transparent", 'pointBorderColor' => "#000", 'pointBackgroundColor' => "#000", 'pointRadius' => "5", 'pointHoverRadius' => "10",'data'=>$data);
            $arrReturn = array(array('labels' => $months, 'datasets' => $arrDatasets));
            print (json_encode($arrReturn, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: lineChartData
});
```

Возможно так?
Советую глянуть тут - https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.7.3/charts/line.html

Comment: а на что здесь может ругаться?
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'datasets' on string '[{"labels":["Январь","Февраль"],"datasets":{"label":"Продано","borderColor":"#000","backgroundColor":"transparent","pointBorderColor":"#000","pointBackgroundColor":"#000","pointRadius":"5","pointHoverRadius":"10","data":["7750.00","15345.00"]}}]'

Comment: @Ssasha, можете это сообщение в основное как правку поместить?
Пока могу сказать только, что вы не можете получить данные о строках Datasets

Comment: сейчас, внесу в вопрос

Comment: @Ssasha, попробуйте lineChartData = JSON.parse(data), но это не точно

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: внес код в правку